# Issue handling Lambda errors in Go

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework

I recently found an article that has a very specific suggestion for handling errors in Go and Lambda: https://hackernoon.com/error-handling-with-api-gateway-and-go-lambda-functions-fe0e10808732

I'm having trouble implementing it though. I've taken their lambdaError struct and included it in my source. On an error I'm doing the following:

```
return Response{ StatusCode: 400, Body: "" }, lambdaError{
    code: "INVALID_REQUEST",
    message: "An invalid content structure was provided",
    origErr: err,
}
```

The error reads to logs properly however Lambda sends the request a 502 with the body:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Within serverless.yml I added the template to my response:

```
  user_create:
    handler: bin/user-create
    name: UserCreate
    description: Creates a new user account
    events:
      - http:
          path: user
          method: post
          response:
            statusCodes:
              400:
                pattern: '.*"statusCode":400,.*'
                template: |
                  #set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')))
                  {
                    "code" : "$errorMessageObj.code",
                    "message" : "$errorMessageObj.public_message"
                  }
                headers:
                  Content-Type: "'application/json'"
          cors: true
```

Having trouble sorting this out, could use a pointer or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up determining that the type of "integration" you use matters. There's a couple including `lambda`, `aws-proxy` and `lambda-proxy`. By default it's `lambda-proxy` which means that all requests are handed to the function directly without any integration mapping or templates. You need `lambda` to do that.

The correct answer and what seems to be standard acceptable practice is to always send errors as `nil` and set the status code and response as the response message. If you send and error back Lambda will always return an internal error with 502.

This also means that logging and error tracking are completely up to you. In some cases this is the best approach, if you go the `lambda` integration route you'll have to define headers, accepted body and use the "integration mapping" process properly.

You have to make a decision which way you want to go with Lambda.

For full clarity, you're ALWAYS sending an events.APIGatewayProxyResponse back and nil as a second parameter from your handler. So a successful response would be:

```
return Response{
  Body: body,
  StatusCode: 200,
  Headers: map[string]string{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
}, nil
```

And an error response would simple be the same response structure but with the StatusCode and Body values changed to your response needs.

Lesson learned :-p

Comment: Wow even I missed that one. Another reason serverless should implement a schema and validate it on deployment.